# Django: Display related model as radio button choices

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following models defined:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Page(models.Model):
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test, related_name='pages')

class Question(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page, related_name='questions')

class Answer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    score = models.IntegerField()
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='answers')
```

I need to make a form using `ModelForm` that should display for each page of a specified test a list of question together with their answers, rendered as **radio buttons**.

How should I approach this? In my view, I have the `test_id` and the `page_id` of the current page within the test. Shall I make a `TestForm`, or `PageForm` or even an `AnswerForm`? What is the approach that matches what I need in the most Django-ish mode?

Comment: Why do you say you need to use a ModelForm?

Comment: How can I do this in a simpler way?

Comment: ModelForm does not apply here since it expect you to save some object.. in your case you doing a poll as I see and you need to introduce something like UserAnswer model - and then render your questions and answers in a regular way (no model forms needed or use some dynamic form creation approach) and save what user chooses on backend

Comment: Alright, so I need to render the radio buttons manually, without any Django specific stuff?